# Sort a list with string of integers separated by space

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.x

Python:
I have a 1-D list that has the following structure(each entry is a string of integers separated by space):

```
vals = ["121",
        "121 122",
        "122",
        "122 124",
        "150",
        "171",
        "49",
        "49 122",
        "49 122" "124",
        "49 122" "516",
        "51",
        "51 122",
        "516",
        "8",
        "8 122" "516",
        "8 124",
        "8 171",
        "8 49",
        "8 49" "124",
        "8 49" "516",
        "8 51",
        "8 51" "122",
        "8 516",
        "878",
        ]
```

But I am looking for a sorted order with respect to each integer in the both row as well as column order, i.e., the expected output is

```
vals = [
    "8",
    "8 49",
    "8 49 124",
    "8 49 516",
    "8 51",
    "8 51 122",
    "49",
    "49 122",
    "49 122 124",
    "49 122 516",
    "51",
    "51 122",
    "121",
    "121 122",
    "122",
    "122 124",
    "150",
    "171",
    "516",
    "878",
]
```

I have tried using the `sort()` as well as `sorted()` mechanism, but nothing seems to work
`sort_len = list1.sort(key = int)` --> This is throwing value error as each list is a string of letters seperated.

I want to sort this list by row value, i.e., the first integer in a row (and in case of same row value, i.e., same first integer then go to the next column)

Comment: It can be assumed that each row is column sorted already i.e., each row is in column sorted order

Comment: `key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split()))` might work

Comment: It is still throwing the error:

list1.sort(key = lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split(','))))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '39 41 48'

Comment: @ManojS - **x.split()** not x.split(',')

Comment: Same thing but different `key = lambda x: [int(n) for n in x.split()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is turn each string to integer tuple.

```
print(sorted(vals, key = lambda y: tuple(int(x) for x in y.split())))

['8', '8 49', '8 49 124', '8 49 516', '8 51', '8 51 122', '8 122 516', '8 124', '8 171', '8 516', '49', '49 122', '49 122 124', '49 122 516', '51', '51 122', '121', '121 122', '122', '122 124', '150', '171', '516', '878']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @Lior Cohen.

This indeed works like a charm.


Here is the resultant list:
[
38 <br>
38 39 <br> 
38 39 41<br>
38 39 41 48<br>
38 39 48<br>
38 39 48 110<br>
38 39 48 170<br>
38 39 110<br>
38 39 170<br>
38 41<br>
38 41 48<br>
38 48<br>
38 48 110<br>
38 48 170<br>
38 110<br>
38 170<br>
38 286<br>
39<br>
]

Comment: you're welcome @ManojS. Please consider to upvote the -1 that someone gave when you have the privilege to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by minimum of each row

`list1.sort(key=lambda e:min([int(se) for se in e.split()]))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs @Adithya 

But, in case my current list is like :
[
1004<br>
101<br>
10515<br>
110<br>
1146<br>
38 110<br>
38 170<br>
38 286<br>
38 39<br>
38 39 110<br>
38 39 170<br>
38 39 41<br>
38 39 41 48<br>
38 39 48<br>
38 39 48 110<br>
38 39 48 170<br>
38 41<br>
38 41 48<br>
38 48<br>
38 48 110<br>
38 48 170<br>
39<br>
8<br>
]

Comment: I am seeing an output using the suggested sort as :
[
8<br>
38 39<br>
38 39 110<br>
38 39 170<br>
38 39 41<br>
38 39 41 48<br>
38 39 48<br>
38 39 48 110<br>
38 39 48 170<br>
38 41<br>
38 41 48<br>
38 48<br>
38 48 110<br>
38 48 170<br>
39<br>
101<br>
110<br>
1004<br>
1146<br>
10515<br>
]

The ordering starts failing w.r.t third column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sorted function and also make use of the key parameter in it to sort the values based on your cutomised way.I have written the code for this.Have a look at this:

```
lis =["121","51 122","122 123 23","2 13 4"]
newlis =[]
for i in lis:
    numbers = [int(s) for s in i.split(" ")]
    numbers = [str(s) for s in sorted(numbers)]
    newlis.append(str(" ".join(numbers)))
newlis = sorted(newlis,key = lambda x: [int(s) for s in x.split(" ")][0])
print(newlis)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @PILLI VINEETH.

I tried the method suggested by you, but I am seeing an un-ordered list:
[
37 38 <br>
37 <br>
38 39 170 <br>
38 48 110 <br>
38 170 <br>
38 41 48 <br>
38 39 48 <br>
38 39 41 <br>
38 48 170 <br>
38 41 <br>
38 39 <br>
38 48 <br>
38 39 48 170 <br>
38 <br>
]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do first is separate each string element into a list of ints using

```
[list(map(int, i.split())) for i in vals]
```

and then sort the list by each index of the values going from last to first. Assuming that the length can at most be 3,

```
func = lambda x,p: x[len(x)-p if len(x)-p > 0 else 0]
vals = sorted(vals, key=lambda x: func(x,1))
vals = sorted(vals, key=lambda x: func(x,2))
vals = sorted(vals, key=lambda x: func(x,3))
```

and then your vals will be sorted. for eg, if you run your example vars through this, the output will be

```
[[8], [8, 49], [8, 51], [8, 124], [8, 171], [8, 516], [8, 49124], [8, 49516], [8, 51122], [8, 122516], [49], [49, 122], [49, 122124], [49, 122516], [51], [51, 122], [121], [121, 122], [122], [122, 124], [150], [171], [516], [878]]
```

After that, just convert it back to a string using

```
vals = list(map(lambda x:" ".join([str(i) for i in x]), vals))
```

Full program as a function:

```
def sort_vals(vals):
    vals = [list(map(int, i.split())) for i in vals]

    func = lambda x,p: x[len(x)-p if len(x)-p > 0 else 0]
    vals = sorted(vals, key=lambda x: func(x,1))
    vals = sorted(vals, key=lambda x: func(x,2))
    vals = sorted(vals, key=lambda x: func(x,3))

    vals = list(map(lambda x:" ".join([str(i) for i in x]), vals))
    return vals
```

Answer (score -1):

Separated sorting of cols and rows. No for loop is bit more pythonic

Code:

```
def sort_str(in_str):
    in_lst = [int(s) for s in in_str.split()]
    return ' '.join(str(i) for i in sorted(in_lst))
    
lst = ['121', '121 122', '122', '122 124', '150', '171', '49', '49 122', '49 122 124', '49 122 516', '51', '51 122', '516', '8', '8 122 516', '8 124', '8 171', '8 49', '8 49 124', '8 49 516', '8 51', '8 51 122', '8 516', '878' ]
lst = [sort_str(ele) for ele in lst]
print(lst) # Sorted columns:
lst.sort(key = lambda s : int(s.split()[0]))
print(lst) #Sorted rows
```

Output:

Sorted columns:

```
['121', '121 122', '122', '122 124', '150', '171', '49', '49 122', '49 122 124', '49 122 516', '51', '51 122', '516', '8', '8 122 516', '8 124', '8 171', '8 49', '8 49 124', '8 49 516', '8 51', '8 51 122', '8 516', '878']
```

Sorted rows:

```
['8', '8 122 516', '8 124', '8 171', '8 49', '8 49 124', '8 49 516', '8 51', '8 51 122', '8 516', '49', '49 122', '49 122 124', '49 122 516', '51', '51 122', '121', '121 122', '122', '122 124', '150', '171', '516', '878']
```